# Post request to guzzle sending apikey in header

Tags: php, guzzle

I am new to Guzzle, i am trying to make a POST request to a website.
A custom header with the key of Cole-ApiKey needs to be set for
making a post reqeust , this post request doesn't require username and password but apiKey in the header only.

my code

```
    $url = "https://infoboost.coleinformation.com";
    $body = "Testing Post Request";
    $api_key = "API_KEY_HERE";

    $client = new Client();

    $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'body' => $body,
        'headers' => [
            "Cole-ApiKey" => $api_key
        ]
    ]);

    $response = $r->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: for some reason server is rejecting my request Client error: `POST https://infoboost.coleinformation.com` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: This means it's an error on the server side, not your code. The endpoint does not support a `POST` request.

Comment: that is so strange, its giving json response on postman but when i try with guzzle it doesn't work so strange

Comment: Are you sure it's sending to the same endpoint?

Comment: Here is what i noticed on POSTMAN Body Tab if i click on raw radiobox it works fine but if i tried with application itself it doesn't work .. maybe there is an option of raw data in guzzle?